# Скрытие Title приводит к вылету при нажатии MENU

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Для себя выяснил, что есть три способа скрыть title приложения:

```
1-й в стайлс: <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
2-й в активити: this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
3-й в манифесте: тоже какой-то простой код, не помню уже.
```

Но когда хоть один использую, то при запуске приложения все нормально до тех пор, пока не нажмешь кнопку "MENU" на самом смартфоне. Тогда после небольшой паузы приложение перестает работать. При использовании Fullscreen такого нет.

Кто что может еще посоветовать. Такое выдает и в Android studio и в Eclipse. Обе программы самой последней версии с официального сайта.

**Обновление**

Вот [ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/T6mcqJoPZzBUQ) на файл лога:  Кстати, выдает ошибку, даже если использовать чистый стандартный новый проект.

**Обновление 2**

Вот мой Styles:

```
<resources> 
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Очистил все проекты - ничего не помогло. Может, есть еще способы скрыть title, кроме тех, что я привел?

Comment: мне кажется, что проблема в том, что меню будет показано в ActionBar, если у телефона нет хардварной кнопки меню - проблема в этом.

Comment: я удаляю папку меню, удаляю в активити, в стрингс. Где еще есть хвосты чтоб убрать полностью активность при нажатии кнопки меню?
Мне она вообще не нужна...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже на [баг](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61394) в библиотеке AppCompat.
В качестве решения просто отлавливайте событие нажатия кнопки в вашем Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
        // никак не обрабатывать
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, все, как надо, теперь)) Спасибо, что откликнулись)